# Add css class to tr if it is even

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-core

I am adding dynamic row in table using below code.

Now I want to check if this added row is odd OR even, if it is even then apply some css class to tr otherwise do not apply that css class.

Any idea how I can get this working.

```
$('#templateListData > tbody:last-child').append('<tr id=row_' + response.id + '> <td scope=row style=min-width: 60px;word-break:break-all;>' + response.name + '</td> <td scope=row style=word-break:break-all;min-width: 50px;>' + response.code + '</td> <td> <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" target=_blank href=/Template/Edit?id=' + response.id + '> Edit </a> <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick=showDeletePopUp(' + response.id + ',Template); return false;>Remove</button> </td> </tr> ');
```

Comment: Well there is 2 ways. 1: use pure css to style the even/odd rows. then you don't have to worry about it when adding the row. 2: get the index of the last row and determine if that is even or odd.

Comment: Use [`:odd`](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) or `:even` in your css:  `tbody:last-child > tr:last-child:even` no need for js.  Note: `:last-child` and `:even` work independently, so it's not get last-child then filter for even as last-child would always be 1 so always odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do in this way

```
$("#tabaleid tbody tr:even").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Here yellow is just for reference.

Let me know if that works or not, if not then I can give some other suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think jquery already has a solution for this written below:

`$("#TableID tbody tr:even").addClass("even");`

Using this all the even tr of your table will have this class added.

Comment: What is `this` referring to in your answer?

Comment: that was typing mistake have remove it from my edit